# How to upload two files at two different paths in Yii2?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

```
public function actionCreate()
{
        $model = new RoomTypes();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) 
        {
            $imageName_1 = $model->room_type.'_'.'1';
            $model->pic_1 = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'pic_1');
            $model->pic_1->saveAs('uploads/room_pics/'.$imageName_1.'.'.$model->pic_1->extension);
            $model->pic_1 = 'uploads/room_pics/'.$imageName_1.'.'.$model->pic_1->extension;

            $imageName_2 = $model->room_type.'_'.'2';
            $model->pic_2 = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'pic_2');
            $model->pic_2->saveAs('uploads/room_pics/'.$imageName_2.'.'.$model->pic_2->extension);
            $model->pic_2 = 'uploads/room_pics/pic2/'.$imageName_2.'.'.$model->pic_2->extension;
            $model->save();
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else 
        {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }  
}
```

I'm not able to store 2nd image in folder, this code is storing 1st or 2nd image in folder, only one image is getting stored not all two, how to achieve this?

**Update:**
**Model - **

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [[/*'room_number','total_people', 'room_type', 'total_count', 'extra_beds', 'pic_1', 'pic_2', 'status', 'rate', 'adults_count', 'child_count'*/], 'required'],
            [['room_number','total_people','total_count', 'extra_beds', 'rate', 'adults_count', 'child_count'], 'integer'],
            [['status'], 'string'],
            [['pic_1', 'pic_2'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg', 'maxFiles' => 4],
            [['room_type'], 'string', 'max' => 40],
            [['description'], 'string', 'max' => 300],
            [['pic_1', 'pic_2'], 'string', 'max' => 500]
        ];
    }
```

Comment: try with multiple file input and its less error prone.

Comment: which file is stored and which is not? Is the directory that you prepare to store the image exists?

Comment: @cedricliang.. its getting randomly stored..

Comment: @CrazzySkulll..ya but how to achieve multiple file uload?

Comment: If room_type is not unique then it will overwrite old image with new one.

Comment: @Ali - means u r saying to make room_type unique?

Comment: First of all delete all images from these 2 upload directories and also truncate table then try to upload and check about this issue

Answer (score 0):

Seem you have a wrong name in `$model->pic_2` assignment I see  `/pic2/` in kmore

```
$model->pic_2 = 'uploads/room_pics/pic2/'.$imageName_2.'.'.$model->pic_2->extension;

$model->pic_1 = 'uploads/room_pics/'.$imageName_1.'.'.$model->pic_1->extension;
```

In the below  lines of code the pathname don't match for me

In the second i see a `pic2` for more

```
        $model->pic_1->saveAs('uploads/room_pics/'.$imageName_1.'.'.$model->pic_1->extension);
        $model->pic_1 = 'uploads/room_pics/'.$imageName_1.'.'.$model->pic_1->extension;

        $model->pic_2->saveAs('uploads/room_pics/'.$imageName_2.'.'.$model->pic_2->extension);
        $model->pic_2 = 'uploads/room_pics/pic2/'.$imageName_2.'.'.$model->pic_2->extension;
```

In the two section   or don't match in saveAs or don't match in assignement and when yuo retreive the path you don't found the picture file

Comment: Hi.. No its right, i tried to woth two different folderd but still not working, its storing only one image randomly may be first or second..

Comment: but the name of the pathname in the secondo saveAs and the pathname  assigned to the model are different. Think this don't match

Comment: because of pic2 folder will contain 2nd image, anyway can u help me with multiple file upload, this solution is not optimal, multiple file upload will be better option.

Comment: You can open a new question in SO. But if you are not convinced of what you do remember that others give you suggestions devoting the time and did not see it like that is not the subject of real interest.